# Make Accurate gestures in Gesture Builder

Tags: android, gesture, gestures

I'm creating an App based on gestures overlay.

For that i have defined my gestures in gesture builder but since they are defined by Free-Hand Drawing that are not quite accurate after being tested in accurate

Is there any way to make Straight Line Gestures in Gesture Builder ?

Please Help

Comment: did you find any solution for your problem

Comment: No. I had to implement My script Calculator's API in my Ap0